# Why am I getting a NullPointerException after upgrading to viewBinding in my Kotlin project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

Recently I upgraded my project from kotlin synthetic to viewBinding. Now I am facing the following crash and I don't know why and from where it is happening,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
                    at com.tigerit.signalmessenger.ui.viewmodels.ConversationThreadListViewModel$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onChanged(Unknown Source:4)
                    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
                    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
                    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
                    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:93)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:241)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:342)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8131)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:583)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
```

I have include views in my xml. Can this be the problem?

Comment: Did you take all the synthetics out of imports

Comment: I had to recheck my code several times within fragments, and activities to make sure I got rid of the imports that used synthetics andb double check everything was correct

Comment: Easy way to remove them all would be to remove the android extensions plugin and then any remaining use of synthetics would trigger compile errors.

Comment: From the stack trace we can see that the error seems to be in one of your live data observers. We can't tell you exactly what you did wrong without seeing the code.